# Undefined references when building GLFW/OpenGL program?

Tags: c, gcc, opengl, mingw, glfw

I am trying to use C, MINGW and GLFW to create a program and I keep on getting this error when compiling.

```
cc1.exe: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: y
cc1.exe: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: n
cc1.exe: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: m
cc1.exe: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: i
cc1.exe: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: c
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `CreateDCW@16'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x160): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1ca): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x24b): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x291): undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x9ee): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xa07): undefined reference to `GetDeviceCaps@8'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xe9f): undefined reference to `CreateDCW@16'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xeba): undefined reference to `GetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0xec8): undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x100e): undefined reference to `CreateDCW@16'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1029): undefined reference to `SetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_monitor.c.obj):win32_monitor.c:(.text+0x1037): undefined reference to `DeleteDC@4'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `CreateDIBSection@24'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x262): undefined reference to `CreateBitmap@20'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x28d): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x37b): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0x389): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0xb55): undefined reference to `CreateRectRgn@16'
./libs/libglfw3.a(win32_window.c.obj):win32_window.c:(.text+0xc2c): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
./libs/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x6c4): undefined reference to `DescribePixelFormat@16'
./libs/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0xbbd): undefined reference to `DescribePixelFormat@16'
./libs/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0xf46): undefined reference to `SwapBuffers@4'
./libs/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x1254): undefined reference to `ChoosePixelFormat@8'
./libs/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x126f): undefined reference to `SetPixelFormat@12'
./libs/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x1592): undefined reference to `DescribePixelFormat@16'
./libs/libglfw3.a(wgl_context.c.obj):wgl_context.c:(.text+0x15d9): undefined reference to `SetPixelFormat@12'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my code

```
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB

int main() {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit()) return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

So its basically just the given example on glfw website.

I use this command to build:

```
gcc -o Test.o Main.c -IGLFW -IGL -dynamic ./libs/glfw3.dll ./libs/glew32.dll -lopengl32 -static ./libs/libglfw3.a ./libs/glew32.lib ./libs/glew32s.lib
```

I dont have any issues with compiling the glfw but I have problems with GLEW, maybe it is because it is lib files instead of a.

Comment: As you can see it can't recognize the `-dynamic` option. Why did you put it there? Did you see it in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: Did you mean `-rdynamic`?

Comment: when I remove -dynamic I still have the same issues just without unrecognized debug option

Comment: ...why are you using `-I` like it's `-L`?

Comment: I did that bcs of where my included headers are situated, I will probably change it soon just to make it neater.